# How to tag some types to build a type list from these tagged types at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, c-preprocessor

I generated some types with an external tool. I include some of them depending on the application. I tried to play with both boost preprocessor and boost mpl to tag my generated types and build an mpl vector of these tagged types.
Unfortunately, my trick only works when I am including the headers I need in a single file with my TypeRegistry.

```
// TypeRegistry.h
typedef ::boost::mpl::vector<> TypeRegistryRegisteredTypes0;

# define TYPE_REGISTRY_REGISTER_TYPE(T)            \
  typedef ::boost::mpl::push_back<                 \
      BOOST_PP_CAT(                                \
          TypeRegistryRegisteredTypes,             \
          BOOST_PP_COUNTER                         \
      ),                                           \
      ##T                                          \
  >::type                                          \
  BOOST_PP_CAT(TypeRegistryRegisteredTypes, BOOST_PP_ADD(BOOST_PP_COUNTER,1))

# define TYPE_REGISTRY_SYNC_REGISTERED_TYPES()     \
  typedef BOOST_PP_CAT(                            \
      TypeRegistryRegisteredTypes,                 \
      BOOST_PP_COUNTER                             \
      ) TypeRegistryRegisteredTypes

template
<
    class RegisteredTypesBase,
    class RegisteredTypesVector
>
class TypeRegistry { ... };
```

This is the macro I use to register a type.

```
// A.h
class A : public IBase { ... };
TYPE_REGISTRY_REGISTER_TYPE(A);
#include BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER()
```

Here we are, in a source file, say `main.h`:

```
#include "TypeRegistry.h"
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"
...
TYPE_REGISTRY_SYNC_REGISTERED_TYPES();
TypeRegistry< IBase, TypeRegistryRegisteredTypes > typeRegistry;
auto a = typeRegistry.instanceFromName("A");
auto b = typeRegistry.instanceFromName("B");
auto c = typeRegistry.instanceFromName("C");
```

As I said, the trick only works because I am including all my interesting types --so to say-- at the same time.
How would you perform an automatic type recording without having to include them all in a single file (that is, compiling a source file which is including its header file should be sufficient)?

Comment: Given that each cpp file compiles into its own translation unit, unless you include every type in the concerned translation unit, you cannot access them. There is no way around that, nor any reason I can see why you would try to do otherwise.

Comment: @Razispio, I want to perform automatic type registration.

Comment: Why If you want to register them, you probably want to have their definition in your translation unit though. C++ doesn't give much freedom about manipulating types you don't know (no reflection etc...)